# Is there any way to access the coding keys for an automatically generated Codable conformance?

Tags: ios, swift, serialization

So let's say I have a Codable type like so:

```
struct MyCodable {
    let name: String
    let value: Int
}
```

Presumably, the compiler should generate a set of coding keys like so:

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case name
    case value
}
```

Is there any way to query these coding keys?

For instance, I would like to be able to do the following:

```
for key in MyCodable.CodkingKeys.allCases {
    print(key)
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CodingKeys` enums are generated as `private` nested types (on purpose), so they can't be accessed from outside of the type. In your example, if that loop is written outside of the `MyCodable` type, it will not work; but `MyCodable` *does* have access to its keys internally.

To expose the keys, you will either need to write out the `CodingKeys` enum yourself with a different access modifier (you can offer `CodingKeys` without needing to implement `init(from:)`/`encode(to:)` yourself), or add a method/property on `MyCodable` which exposes the set of coding keys in a way that is appropriate for your use case (e.g. `var codingKeys: [CodingKey] { ... }`).

Answer (score 1):

The synthesized code looks like this:

```
struct MyCodable: Codable {
    let name: String
    let value: Int
    
    // Synthesized by Codable conformance:
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case value
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, as you can see, it's `private` and does not conform to `CaseIterable`. Alternatively you can do that part manually and access the `enum` only inside your struct like so:

```
struct MyCodable: Codable {
    let name: String
    let value: Int
    
    private static var allCases: [CodingKeys] {
        return [.name, .value]
    }
    
    func query() {
        for key in Self.allCases {
            print(key)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, this is a case where the inability to nest an extension inside another type is actually a real restriction. You can't do `extension MyCodable.CodingKeys: CaseIterable { ... }`